# pyodbc.connect not working with aws db instance, while working with local server

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have database connections inside a data pipeline. I am currently having issues using `pyodbc.connect(cnxn_string)` with an aws db-instance. While I can connect using `pyodbc` on local server. Moreover, the connection works when I use `sqlalchemy.create_engine(cnxn_string)`.

example aws db-instance:

`connection = DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=mycompany-db.cu9fhgtuioo.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com;DATABASE=mycompanydatabase;UID=admin;PWD=foobar`

example local server:

`connection = DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=LOCALCOMPANYSERVER-ANALYSIS\ROOT2005;DATABASE=mycompanydatabase;UID=admin;PWD=foobar`

For now, instead of changing several of my packages to use `sqlalchemy` right away, I want to get this working and test the data pipeline. I want to use the `pyodbc` module to connect. I'm hoping there might some modification needed in the connection string to make `pyodbc.connect` work. Note, odbc drivers are installed, the aws instance allows connections (sqlalchemy works).

```
import pyodbc
pyodc.connect(cnxn_string)

#####
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "mycompanydatabase" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing quotations, the odd thing is that the

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "mycompanydatabase" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

is often related to SQL query code, and when a programming error occur, everything fine with that?

```
    pyodbc.connect(
    driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',
    system='=mycompany-db.cu9fhgtuioo.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
    database='mycompanydatabase'
    uid='admin',
    pwd='foobar')
```

I hope I answer your question, if not. tell me and I will do my best to understand your question further.